# How do I setup an HTTP call and response?

Tags: android, http, android-intent, httpresponse

I'm new to programming Android and looking at the example on how to connect to the cloud (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html).  I want to send a POST request to a server and receive a response.

Where do I put the "public class HTTPExampleActivity..." code from the example?  Does that go in my main activity as a second class or do I create a different java file for that class? If the latter, how do I create that document in Eclipse?  is it a "new activity" or something else?

Comment: I think you are new with Android platform and Eclipse. You have to learn basic things which helps you to create Demo App of Android then you have can easily make this type of application. @Mark

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your choice. It could be within your Activity or could be within a different plain class.

Have a look here :

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-making-http-requests/

http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-http-with-asynctask-example/

Comment: Thanks for the links.  They look very useful.